# How to have 2 inputs in a Dense network with Keras?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

Most tutorials I've followed shows how I can give a single input into the first layer of a Dense network with something like this using Keras:

```
Inp = Input(shape=(1,))
x = Dense(100, activation='relu', name = "Dense_1")(Inp)
x = Dense(100, activation='relu', name = "Dense_2")(x)
output = Dense(50, activation='softmax', name = "outputL")(x)
```

However, if I want to provide 2 or more inputs into the first layer of a Dense network, how can I do so with Keras? The idea is just simply to have 2 inputs of `x1` and `x2`, like this:
[image]

I've tried something like this which I've modified from snippets found on one of the pages in the Keras documentation:

```
Inp1 = Input(shape=(1,))
Inp2 = Input(shape=(1,))
Inp = keras.layers.concatenate([Inp1, Inp2])
x = Dense(100, activation='relu', name = "Dense_1")(Inp)
x = Dense(100, activation='relu', name = "Dense_2")(x)
output = Dense(50, activation='softmax', name = "outputL")(x)
res = model.fit([x1_train, x2_train], y_train,
                    validation_data=([x1_test, x2_test], y_test))
```

But so the far, the results that I'm getting from the model training appears to have ridiculously low accuracy. Is what I've done what I've actually intended?

Comment: Just to clarify, when you specify the input shape, you're not specifying how many inputs you're going to be passing to your model. Instead, you're specifying the shape of each individual input. This shape will represent the features in each sample. So there's no limit to how many inputs you pass to your model. If, on the other hand, you're simply wanting to pass samples that have more than 1 feature, say 2, then you would specify shape=(2,) in the input layer.

Comment: @blackHoleDetector in my case, I'm trying to pass into the network 2 inputs each of shape=(1,). The output depends on the combination of the input x1 and x2. So each sample of x1 and x2 need to be passed in as inputs together.

Comment: it sounds like you need to have 2-dimensional inputs. For example, an input called X would have 2 dimensions. The first dimension would represent what you called x1, and the second dimension would be x2. Simultaneously passing two separate inputs to the model that depend on each other wouldn't conceptually make sense.

Comment: Can you describe what your output is? I see it has 50 elements. But what are they? You're using a softmax activation, meaning you want only one of the 50 elements to be true. If that is not your case, you shouldn't be using softmax at all. Use sigmoid instead. Also, do your outputs range from 0 to 1? Softmax and sigmoid will never output negative numbers or numbers grater than 1.

Comment: Well 2 inputs to predict 50 classes in not providing the network with a ton of information. How many samples do you have total?

Comment: I think you can just cancat the two input `X1` and `X2`, combine them before input,  then you can put two input variables into one node. I think the reason  you get a low acc is because you have a bad training set instead of the network structure, I think the network is fine for you to complete your task, if you really want to use a two-dimensions input to generate a 50-dims of output.